# How to emit a final item after all the items in the Flowable are emitted

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to emit a final item after all the items in the `Flowable` are emitted. For now I can achieve this via the following code.

```
Flowable<String> flowable = getFlowable();
flowable.toList()
        .toFlowable()
        .flatMap(stringList -> {
            stringList.add("final String");
            return Flowable.just(stringList);
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The problem is, it waits until all the items are obtained before emitting. I want them to be emitted immediately when they are obtained, one at a time, and an extra `final String` could be emitted right after the last item, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concatWith`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html)

```
flowable.concatWith(Flowable.just(stringList))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```